# Transformer: Why doesn't the softmax in the classification layer (i.e. FFNN with a softmax) need scaling input which same operation as self-attention?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, transformer-model, softmax, attention-model

The reason why the scaled self-attention need to be scaled, said in the original paper, is that "dot products grow large in magnitude, pushing the softmax function into regions where it has extremely small gradients".

So if the problem is a large value or some large value in the input will make the gradient of softmax sparse, why doesn’t the last layer of Transformer (classification layer, i.e. feed-forward network with a softmax) need scaling input?

In other words, we know that softmax is a very common function in machine learning, why is it only accept scaled input in self-attention scenarios?